# Storing Music to stream w/ PG, Nodejs

Tags: node.js, postgresql, audio-player

I'm looking to add an audio streamer to my personal website to play music I have created. I'm unsure as to how to store the mp3 files in postgres database. I've seen some reference to storing it in the file system and then having a reference to that file in the db? can someone elaborate on this? Links to docs would be amazing!

So far I've only been researching and haven't really tried anything specific yet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to decide whether to store binary data in Postgres or in files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239804/how-to-decide-whether-to-store-binary-data-in-postgres-or-in-files)